# Jquery mmenu: How to launch with all submenus open?

Tags: mmenu

This may be a simple question.
I have a working menu with 
slidingSubmenus: false
so clicking on submenus opens them up. 
(I'm also using widescreen as I want the menu to always appear).

However they all start with menu collapsed. How do I launch it with all submenus open (expanded?)

Answer (score 3):

Add `mm-opened` class to the submenu's parent `LI` tag.